# cambiar el total automáticamente cuando se modifique el subtotal

Tags: javascript, html

lo que quiero hacer es que el total se modifique y no se siga sumando cuando el subtotal tenga otro valor al cambiar la cantidad o el precio, saludos y gracias de antemano!!!

```js
    function calculo(cantidad,precio,inputtext,totaltext){
      
      /* Parametros:
      cantidad - entero con la cantidad
      precio - entero con el precio
      inputtotal - nombre del elemento del formulario donde ira el total
      */
      
      // Calculo del subtotal
      subtotal = precio*cantidad;
      inputtext.value=subtotal;
      
      //Actualizar el total
      // Utilizamos el eval. Ya que el valor es un texto y si lo tratamos como tal
      // es como si estuviesemos manipulando una cadena.
     total = eval(totaltext.value);
      totaltext.value = total + subtotal;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Cantidad</td>
    <td>Precio</td>
    <td>subTotal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Platanos</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="3" id="platanos" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,precioplatanos.value,totalplatanos,total);">uds</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="precioplatanos" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,platanos.value,totalplatanos,total);"/> 7€</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="8" id="totalplatanos" value="0">€</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Manzanas</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="3" id="manzanas" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,preciomanzanas.value,totalmanzanas,total);">uds</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="preciomanzanas" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,manzanas.value,totalmanzanas,total);"/>3€</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="8" id="totalmanzanas" value="0">€</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Peras</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="3" id="peras" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,precioperas.value,totalperas,total);">uds</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="precioperas" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,peras.value,totalperas,total);">2€</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="8" id="totalperas" value="0">€</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Uvas</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="3" id="uvas" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,preciouvas.value,totaluvas,total);">uds</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="preciouvas" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,uvas.value,totaluvas,total);"/>9€</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="8" id="totaluvas" value="0">€</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Melocotones</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="3" id="melocotones" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,preciomelocotones.value,totalmelocotones,total);">uds</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="preciomelocotones" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,melocotones.value,totalmelocotones,total);"/>5€</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="8" id="totalmelocotones" value="0">€</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="total" size="8" value="0">€</td>
    </tr></table>
    
    </body>
```

Comment: <script>

function calculo(cantidad,precio,inputtext,totaltext){
  
  /* Parametros:
  cantidad - entero con la cantidad
  precio - entero con el precio
  inputtotal - nombre del elemento del formulario donde ira el total
  */
  
  // Calculo del subtotal
  subtotal = precio*cantidad;
  inputtext.value=subtotal;
  
  //Actualizar el total
  // Utilizamos el eval. Ya que el valor es un texto y si lo tratamos como tal
  // es como si estuviesemos manipulando una cadena.
 total = eval(totaltext.value);
  totaltext.value = total + subtotal;
}

Answer (score 7):

Puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo:

- Pones a los subtotales una clase `subtotal`
- Los alcanzas todos mediante `querySelectorAll` basándote en esa clase
- Haces una suma en directo de los valores de cada elemento.
- Actualizas el `input` el total general.

He mejorado algunas cosas en tu código:

- Los inputs calculados no deberían estar disponibles para el usuario, porque éste podría meter mano allí, cambiar valores y estropearlo todo, por eso los he declarado como `readonly`
- No pasa caaada vez en parámetro el elemento del total, es mucho más simple obtenerlo directamente en JS por su id.
- El código es *NaN safe*  gracias a esta línea: `var subtotal = precio * cantidad || 0;` que hace que el valor del subtotal sea `0` cuando se introduzca un valor `NaN` (Not a Number) en los inputs. Prueba por ejemplo a introducir letras en cualquiera de los inputs.

Otras cosas se podrían mejorar, pero sería ya alejarse demasiado del propósito de la pregunta.

Este código te actualiza los totales cada vez que algo cambie en cualquiera de ellos. Prueba por ejemplo un escenario donde el cliente pide 5 plátanos, luego ve que están tan bonitos que se arrepiente y en vez de 5 quiere 7 en total. Vas a ver que el total general se actualiza solo.

Espero te sirva.

```js
function calculo(cantidad, precio, inputtext, totaltext) {

  /* Parametros:
  cantidad - entero con la cantidad
  precio - entero con el precio
  inputtotal - nombre del elemento del formulario donde ira el total
  */
  // Calculo del subtotal
  var subtotal = precio * cantidad || 0;
  inputtext.value = subtotal;
  var elTotal = document.getElementById('total');
  var allSubTotals = document.querySelectorAll('.subtotal');
  var totalGlobal = 0;
  var totalParcial = 0;
  allSubTotals.forEach(function(item) {
    totalParcial += parseInt(item.value);
  });


  //Actualizar el total
  // Utilizamos el eval. Ya que el valor es un texto y si lo tratamos como tal
  // es como si estuviesemos manipulando una cadena.
  //total = eval(totaltext.value);
  elTotal.value = totalParcial;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Cantidad</td>
    <td>Precio</td>
    <td>subTotal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Platanos</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="3" id="platanos" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,precioplatanos.value,totalplatanos);">uds</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="precioplatanos" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,platanos.value,totalplatanos);" /> 7€</td>
    <td><input class="subtotal" type="text" size="8" id="totalplatanos" value="0" readonly />€</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Manzanas</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="3" id="manzanas" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,preciomanzanas.value,totalmanzanas);">uds</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="preciomanzanas" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,manzanas.value,totalmanzanas);" />3€</td>
    <td><input class="subtotal" type="text" size="8" id="totalmanzanas" value="0" readonly />€</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peras</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="3" id="peras" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,precioperas.value,totalperas);">uds</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="precioperas" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,peras.value,totalperas);">2€</td>
    <td><input class="subtotal" type="text" size="8" id="totalperas" value="0" readonly />€</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Uvas</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="3" id="uvas" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,preciouvas.value,totaluvas);">uds</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="preciouvas" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,uvas.value,totaluvas,total);" />9€</td>
    <td><input class="subtotal" type="text" size="8" id="totaluvas" value="0" readonly />€</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Melocotones</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="3" id="melocotones" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,preciomelocotones.value,totalmelocotones);">uds</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="preciomelocotones" value="0" oninput="calculo(this.value,melocotones.value,totalmelocotones);" />5€</td>
    <td><input class="subtotal" type="text" size="8" id="totalmelocotones" value="0" readonly />€</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="total" size="8" value="0" readonly>€</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```